# Multiply View/Nested views without using ui-routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I am working on a angular project, where they have used ng-routes in the project, And now I have to create a page/view which has  3 dropdowns, and 3 tabs, the dropdowns are common for 3 tabs, 
And each tabs has a complex set of highcharts and accordions involved.

As you can see in the image attached, 'display part' should change every time the user clicks on the links page1, page2, page3, keeping the dropdowns unchanged, and should be available inside display area   please suggest me any idea with step by step, other than ui-routes, as my project is already been done using ng-routing.

NOTE: The views/templates of all 3 tabs are not same, first tab has a highchart with a accordion, second tab has a nested Div with some progress bar kind of data, third tab, the UI is not yet decided, Overall the views will be different from each other.

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: could be as simple as changing the data object(s) passed to view html within your display area. Question is too broad

Comment: This would have worked, if the views/templates of all 3 tabs are same, but the views are different from each other tabs. first tab has a highchart with a accordion, second tab has a nested Div with some progress bar kind of data, third tab, the UI is not yet decided, Overall the views will be different from each other